# python - recursively deleting dict keys?

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary, plist

I'm using Python 2.7 with `plistlib` to import a .plist in a nested dict/array form, then look for a particular key and delete it wherever I see it.

When it comes to the actual files we're working with in the office, I already know where to find the values -- but I wrote my script with the idea that I didn't, in the hopes that I wouldn't have to make changes in the future if the file structure changes or we need to do likewise to other similar files.

Unfortunately I seem to be trying to modify a dict while iterating over it, but I'm not certain how that's actually happening, since I'm using `iteritems()` and `enumerate()` to get generators and work with those instead of the object I'm actually working with.

```
def scrub(someobject, badvalue='_default'): ##_default isn't the real variable
    """Walks the structure of a plistlib-created dict and finds all the badvalues and viciously eliminates them.

Can optionally be passed a different key to search for."""
    count = 0

    try:
        iterator = someobject.iteritems()
    except AttributeError:
        iterator = enumerate(someobject)

    for key, value in iterator:
        try:
            scrub(value)
        except:
            pass
        if key == badvalue:
            del someobject[key]
            count += 1

    return "Removed {count} instances of {badvalue} from {file}.".format(count=count, badvalue=badvalue, file=file)
```

Unfortunately, when I run this on my test .plist file, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "formscrub.py", line 45, in <module>
    scrub(loadedplist)
  File "formscrub.py", line 19, in scrub
    for key, value in iterator:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

So the problem might be the recursive call to itself, but even then shouldn't it just be removing from the original object? I'm not sure how to avoid recursion (or if that's the right strategy) but since it's a .plist, I do need to be able to identify when things are dicts or lists and iterate over them in search of either (a) more dicts to search, or (b) the actual key-value pair in the imported .plist that I need to delete.

Ultimately, this is a *partial* non-issue, in that the files I'll be working with on a regular basis have a known structure. However, I was really hoping to create something that doesn't care about the nesting or order of the object it's working with, as long as it's a Python dict with arrays in it.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Ah geez :/ i didn't even get to the relevant conundrum

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Adding or removing items to/from a sequence while iterating over this sequence is tricky at best, and just illegal (as you just discovered) with dicts. The right way to remove entries from a dict while iterating over it is to iterate on a snapshot of the keys. In Python 2.x, `dict.keys()` provides such a snapshot. So for dicts the solution is:

```
for key in mydict.keys():
    if key == bad_value:
        del mydict[key]
```

As mentionned by cpizza in a comment, for python3, you'll need to explicitely create the snapshot using `list()`:

```
for key in list(mydict.keys()):
    if key == bad_value:
        del mydict[key]
```

For lists, trying to iterate on a snapshot of the indexes (ie `for i in len(thelist):`) would result in an IndexError as soon as anything is removed (obviously since at least the last index will no more exist), and even if not you might skip one or more items (since the removal of an item makes the sequence of indexes out of sync with the list itself). `enumerate` is safe against IndexError (since the iteration will stop by itself when there's no more 'next' item in the list, but you'll still skip items:

```
>>> mylist = list("aabbccddeeffgghhii")
>>> for x, v  in enumerate(mylist):
...     if v in "bdfh":
...         del mylist[x]
>>> print mylist
['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'i']
```

Not a quite a success, as you can see.

The known solution here is to iterate on reversed indexes, ie:

```
>>> mylist = list("aabbccddeeffgghhii")
>>> for x in reversed(range(len(mylist))):
...     if mylist[x] in "bdfh":
...         del mylist[x]
>>> print mylist
['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'g', 'g', 'i', 'i']
```

This works with reversed enumeration too, but we dont really care.

So to summarize: you need two different code path for dicts and lists - and you also need to take care of "not container" values (values which are neither lists nor dicts), something you do not take care of in your current code.

```
def scrub(obj, bad_key="_this_is_bad"):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        # the call to `list` is useless for py2 but makes
        # the code py2/py3 compatible
        for key in list(obj.keys()):
            if key == bad_key:
                del obj[key]
            else:
                scrub(obj[key], bad_key)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for i in reversed(range(len(obj))):
            if obj[i] == bad_key:
                del obj[i]
            else:
                scrub(obj[i], bad_key)

    else:
        # neither a dict nor a list, do nothing
        pass
```

As a side note: **never** write a bare except clause. Never **ever**. This should be illegal syntax, really.

Comment: Perhaps my understanding of what an iterator is, is incomplete. I understood it to exist independent of the object it represented. Maybe that's wrong. Nonetheless, unless I've implemented your suggestion incorrectly, this leads to `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`. Silencing that error (explicitly) just leads to a max recursion depth error.

Comment: @Stick : Your understanding of iterators is indeed incomplete. You'll find the official doc here : http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types. wrt/ TypeError, the code you posted has the same problem obviously - try `enumerate(42)`.

Comment: @Stick : revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to be so clear. So, is this a situation where `isinstance()` is preferable to a `try/except`? I knew that I'd want to try and treat dicts and lists differently, but I tried to avoid type checking (perhaps incorrectly - I'd just as soon check all kinds of types, but apparently it is just not considered Pythonic and so one tends to get negative attention for using it). Is there a clear advantage to this approach as opposed to the more often seen `if isinstance(obj, basestring): pass; try: treat_as_dict(); except __Error: treat_as_list()`?

Comment: There are just too many iterable types (and a few non-builtin non-dict types with a subpart of a `dict` API) to expect a fully generic yet simple and maintainable code, so better to stick to KISS and YAGNI. This solution _should_ work for any combination of dicts and lists, so you already have your bases covered. If you end up having more types to handle I'd suggest going for something like Py3 GenericFunctions ( http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0443/) - there's at least one implemention for 2.x (cf http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#abcs-vs-generic-functions).

Comment: Oh and yes: there's nothing wrong with typechecking in itself - like any other "golden rule" it's mostly a matter of understanding when the rule applies and when it doesn't. What we're doing here is not type-based restriction but (the most primitive form of) type-based dispatch.

Comment: for python 3 the third line of the `scrub` method should read `for k in list(obj.keys())` — without creating a copy of the list it breaks because of iterating over a modified dictionary after the key deletion.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I updated the code above to actually run.

Answer (score 7):

Here a generalized version of the one of @bruno desthuilliers, with a `callable` to test against the keys.

```
def clean_dict(obj, func):
    """
    This method scrolls the entire 'obj' to delete every key for which the 'callable' returns
    True

    :param obj: a dictionary or a list of dictionaries to clean
    :param func: a callable that takes a key in argument and return True for each key to delete
    """
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        # the call to `list` is useless for py2 but makes
        # the code py2/py3 compatible
        for key in list(obj.keys()):
            if func(key):
                del obj[key]
            else:
                clean_dict(obj[key], func)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for i in reversed(range(len(obj))):
            if func(obj[i]):
                del obj[i]
            else:
                clean_dict(obj[i], func)

    else:
        # neither a dict nor a list, do nothing
        pass
```

And an example with a regex callable :

```
func = lambda key: re.match(r"^<div>", key)

clean_dict(obj, func)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the code to delete the key recursively from any object.

```
def remove_keys_recursively(dict_obj, keys):
    for key in list(dict_obj.keys()):
        if not isinstance(dict_obj, dict):
            continue
        elif key in keys:
            dict_obj.pop(key, None)
        elif isinstance(dict_obj[key], dict):
            remove_keys_recursively(dict_obj[key], keys)
        elif isinstance(dict_obj[key], list):
            for item in dict_obj[key]:
                remove_keys_recursively(item, keys)
    return
```

Output:

```
>>> d = {1:{2:3}, 2:{3:4}, 5:{6:{2:3}, 7:{1:2, 2:3}}, 3:4}
>>>
>>> d
{1: {2: 3}, 2: {3: 4}, 5: {6: {2: 3}, 7: {1: 2, 2: 3}}, 3: 4}
>>>
>>> keys = [2]
>>>
>>> remove_keys_recursively(d, keys)
>>>
>>> d
{1: {}, 5: {6: {}, 7: {1: 2}}, 3: 4}
```

Comment: Easy to read, and easy to understand solution. Thank you!

Comment: The `if not isinstance(dict_obj, dict):` check seems to be in the wrong place? Having it inside the loop doesn't make sense because if it's not a dict then `.keys()` probably already failed on the line above.

Answer (score 0):

```
def walk(d, badvalue, answer=None, sofar=None):
    if sofar is None:
        sofar = []
    if answer is None:
        answer = []
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        if k == badvalue:
            answer.append(sofar + [k])
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            walk(v, badvalue, answer, sofar+[k])
    return answer

def delKeys(d, badvalue):
    for path in walk(d, badvalue):
        dd = d
        while len(path) > 1:
            dd = dd[path[0]]
            path.pop(0)
        dd.pop(path[0])
```

Output

```
In [30]: d = {1:{2:3}, 2:{3:4}, 5:{6:{2:3}, 7:{1:2, 2:3}}, 3:4}

In [31]: delKeys(d, 2)

In [32]: d
Out[32]: {1: {}, 3: 4, 5: {6: {}, 7: {1: 2}}}
```

Comment: this would be pretty stellar if .plists were just nested dicts, but unfortunately the ones i'm working with also produce arrays. But i like this a lot and I think it's a move in the right direction

Comment: If you could post an example of the data structure you're dealing with, I could try to update my answer